# Taking one positional argument but more than one given

Tags: python, multithreading, image

I have some code that uses pybing image_search to download pictures but my threading seems to have a problem

```
    import pickle
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import threading


search_terms = ['Clint Eastwood', 'George Clooney']

def downloader():
    for search_term in search_terms:
        t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=(str(search_term)))
        print("started thread for %s" %search_term)
        t.start()

def getter(search_term):


    list_of_lists = pickle.load(open('%s/pickle_dump.p' %search_term, 'rb'))
    count = 1
    print(list_of_lists)
    for list in list_of_lists:
        print(list)

        for i in list:
            try:
                link = i.media_url
                print('retrieving %s-%s' %(str(count),str(i)))
                urlretrieve(link, "%s/%s-%s.jpg" % (search_term, str(count), str(i)))
            except:
                pass
        count += 1
```

getter() opens a list of lists, each place in the list holds a pybing image object which I can use to get a link for an image, but when running function downloader(), it says getter takes one positional argument, but 14 were given which is confusing, as I only pass a string into it for each thread any help?

Answer (score 0):

`(str(search_term))` is not a tuple; `(str(search_term),)` is. In your code, `getter` is receiving a list of arguments, one character of `search_term` per argument.

Comment: thanks man, just worked that out, as the strings in search term happened to have 14 characters, thank you for that, appreciated